# Can a slackbot pull messages from a private channel and post in another slack channel?

Tags: automation, bots, slack, slack-api, zapier

I am wondering if a slack bot can pull messages that are tagged with a certain string of characters from a private channel and then post that "tagged" message in another channel (private or public). All within the same slack group.

Comment: Elaborate more in detail

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Slack bot can do that. But he needs to be invited to a channel (public and private) to be able to monitor it. He then receives all messages in that channel and can react to it in any way you want. Bots can only use a subset of all Slack API methods, but yes they can post a copy of a message to another channel based on keywords.

See the [Slack documentation](https://api.slack.com/bot-users) on bots for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Also try setting up a webhook from that slack channel, I've had success with that

Comment: Note that webhooks will not work for private channels though

Comment: It can now. You have to add a "bot event" and subscribe to "message.groups".